# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline : running a script{} block outside of stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

**Goal:**

I need to run a snippet similar to this, in order to grab some info from a different Jenkins job:

```
 script {
    def buildJobName = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('Jobs/myOtherJob')
    def buildJobId = buildJobName.getLastSuccessfulBuild()
 }
```

The documentation explains clearly how a script can be ran in a Declarative Pipeline: 
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script but it explicitly runs them within stages.

> *This question scope is specifically about how to run "any" script block outside of pipeline stages, so it's not specific what my script is doing. Can be applied to any groovy script in a declarative pipeline.*

---

**My use-case will need this data globally, outside of the scope of a single step**

Normally, for "global" things across the whole pipeline, I use the **`environment{}` block to declare variables.** However, I can't seem to get the script to execute properly in the `environment{}` block, at least with the attempts I've made.

**So, my question is:**

How can I run a script section in a declarative pipeline, defining variables that can be later used in the entire pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out after doing some more research.

There might be a more optimal way, but I was able to get this working by putting the script in a function, and setting the env var value to the functions return value:

```
def get_last_build() {
  def buildJobName = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('Jobs/myOtherJob')
  def lastBuildId = buildJobName.getLastSuccessfulBuild()
  echo 'Using Build ID: ' + lastBuildId
  return lastBuildId
}

pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    MY_GLOBAL_VAR = get_last_build()
  }
  // other stuff
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's other alternative with declarative pipelines ;)
You can put it in other file if you need to reuse it somewhere else tho